# Tensorflow installed but not working in Windows 10

Tags: python, tensorflow

I installed tensorflow 1.8.0 as verified by `pip show tensorflow`:

```
PS C:\> pip show tensorflow
Name: tensorflow
Version: 1.8.0
Summary: TensorFlow helps the tensors flow
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages
Requires: tensorboard, grpcio, absl-py, astor, wheel, protobuf, numpy, six, 
gast, termcolor
Required-by:
PS C:\>
```

But when I tried to test a simple program named `tensorflow.py`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

I received an error:

```
PS C:\Users\Steven\.atom> python .\tensorflow.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\tensorflow.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\Steven\.atom\tensorflow.py", line 2, in <module>
    hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'constant'
```

I am running the command in Windows Power Shell. My OS is 64-bit Windows 10 with Python 3.6.5. Can someone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file is named `tensorflow.py`, causing it to shadow the `tensorflow` module. When Python looks for `tensorflow.constant` it will try to find it its definition *in your file*.

Rename your file to something different. Something like `hello_tf.py` might be a good choice.

Comment: Changing the file, I don't receive the error but get a new one: ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'. Can you help me with this as well? I'll accept your answer though since you answer my original question.

Comment: @StevenChan, Stack Overflow works best with one question per post. Your new error appears to be quite different from the first one. Please search for that error message—it appears to be common when using TensorFlow on Windows with your GPU. If you are unable to find a solution, please post a new question.